# sp_add_jobstep add more than 4000 Character in @command parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

sp_add_jobstep is well documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-jobstep-transact-sql).  I understand parameter `@command` is type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

I am creating a SQL Agent Job using a Stored Procedure.  Passing the value for `@command` parameter via a variable.  I am getting truncated at 4000 character.

My variable is also declared as NVARCHAR(MAX)

Any workaround to add more than 4000 characters in `@command` parameter?

Comment: "@command" is nvarchar(max). Although if you need to go higher I'd be looking at moving the code into a stored proc/file, for readability if nothing else!

Comment: @GarethLyons  Yes I see that, Not sure what I was thinking. Edited my question. thx.

Comment: np, just tried it on SQL2014 / SSMS 2014, happily accepts & displays commands over 4000 characters. What versions are you on? Thanks

Comment: sql2016/ssms2016 are you passing it as a variable? `DECLARE @command1 NVARCHAR(MAX)` then ` @command=@command1` .

Comment: Yep, and just tried successfully on 16/16 too. Maybe a rogue apostrophe somewhere?

Comment: @GarethLyons I thought about that. So I started deleting some white space and linefeed from the top and I do see additional characters (same amount that I clean up at the top).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `N` before every termination of string.  What I mean by that?

Before I did not had `N` after `@dbName` and `@tblUpdateStats_List` variables.

```
 DECLARE @command2 NVARCHAR(MAX)   
 SET @command2 =N'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED  
                USE [' + @dbName +']
                INSERT INTO [DBA].[dbo].['+@tblUpdateStats_List+'] ....................
```

Added `N` after `@dbName` and `@tblUpdateStats_List` and now I can pass more than 4000 character to `@command` parameter.

```
DECLARE @command2 NVARCHAR(MAX)   
     SET @command2 =N'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED  
                    USE [' + @dbName +N']
                    INSERT INTO [DBA].[dbo].['+@tblUpdateStats_List+N']..................
```

Answer (score 1):

`'This'` is a `varchar` string.

`N'This'` is an `nvarchar` string.

I'll guess that, after `@tblUpdateStats_List`, the remainder of your string was more than 4000 characters.

I did some experiments (in SQL 2016), and it looks like when a `varchar` string is implicitly converted to `nvarchar`, it is converted to `nvarchar(4000)`, not `nvarchar(MAX)`.

I ran the following query:

```
DECLARE @myNVar NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @myNVar = 'ABCDEFG';

SET @myNVar = 'QQQ' + REPLICATE(@myNVar, 1000)
             +<literal>
             +'QQQ';

SELECT LEN(@myNVar), SUBSTRING(@myNVar, 6990, 25), RIGHT(@myNVar, 20);
```

With `<literal>` initially being an nvarchar string constructed as follows:

- The character 'Z', repeated 3 times
- the character 'z', repeated 1027 times
- the character 'X', repeated 3 times
- EOL
- The resulting string copied, and pasted in 3 more times (wit the fourth EOL removed)

This string was 4,138 characters long (on Windows, where EOL is CR+LF), so the total string length should have been 3 + 7000 + 4138 + 3, or 11,144 characters

When run with the literal as an `nvarchar` string, got the following results:

```
11144     ABCDEFGABCDEFGZZZzzzzzzzz     zzzzzzzzzzzzzzXXXQQQ
```

So, correct length, and expected values at end of replicated string, at start of literal, and at end of literal.

Then, I changed the literal to a `varchar` string, and got this:

```
11006     ABCDEFGABCDEFGZZZzzzzzzzz     zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzQQQ
```

So, length shows 3 + 7000 + 4000 + 3 = 11006 - what we'd expect if the varchar value was truncated down to just 4,000 characters. And, we don't see `XXX` before the final `QQQ`, also as we'd expect under these circumstances.

FYI - If I `CAST` the `varchar` literal to `nvarchar(MAX)`, my results went back to the first ones, so an explicit cast avoids this problem.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with your comment about implicit conversion.  My problem was part of my string was `NVARCHAR` and part was `VARCHAR` . I started with `N` then I had many variables in the string where I did not put `N'`. Once I added `N` in front of every string it did work for me.  After `@tblUpdateStats_List` I have many more strings separated by variables.

Comment: I may have been making this mistake of mixing types in a string for EXEC() or for sp_executesql .  I hadn't identified some combinations as safe and some not, but my workaround for it has been to use just one long string which contains token marker terms like @{explicit_integer} and '@{explicit_string}', into @template nvarchar(max), then, REPLACE() each of the tokens with the required value, instead of inserting by adding strings together.